# How to make a function's solution go back into function and print new solution?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I'm trying to make a function that calculates a percent increase of a number. 
For example, number = 2
increase = 50%

```
number = 2
increase = 50

def numberIncrease(number,increase):
    decimal = increase / 100
    increase_value = number * decimal
    new_number = increase_value + number
    return new_number

year_increase = int(numberIncrease(number,increase))
print(year_increase)
```

I want the solution to this to go back into the function and print new result, and I want it to do this 16 times (not including the first time). So total 17 times. Please let me know how I can do this, thanks!

Comment: do you want to keep feeding the `numberIncrease` with previous results of the same function?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want

Comment: read about loops- for loops f.e. or while loops. There are tutrorials out there that explain them

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `for` loop, it will repeat your code `iterations` times, for example:

```py
number = 2
increase = 50
iterations = 17

def numberIncrease(number,increase):
    decimal = increase / 100
    increase_value = number * decimal
    new_number = increase_value + number
    return new_number

for i in range(iterations):
    year_increase = numberIncrease(number, increase)
    print('Iteration:', i + 1, 'Number:', number, 'Result:', year_increase)
    number = year_increase

>>> Iteration: 1 Number: 2 Result: 3.0
>>> Iteration: 2 Number: 3.0 Result: 4.5
>>> Iteration: 3 Number: 4.5 Result: 6.75
...
>>> Iteration: 17 Number: 1313.6816711425781 Result: 1970.5225067138672
```